# Change offset of label using Cesium JS

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I want to drag a label (or label collection) in Cesium without changing its position.
I thought about changing its `pixelOffset` after I created the label. I did this:

```
            var entity = mapa.getViewer.entities.add({
            position: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-75.1641667, 39.9522222),
            billboard: {
                image: pinBuilder.fromColor(Cesium.Color.SALMON, 48),
                verticalOrigin: Cesium.VerticalOrigin.BOTTOM
            },
            label: {
                text: ' Ponto',
                verticalOrigin: Cesium.VerticalOrigin.TOP,
                horizontalOrigin: Cesium.HorizontalOrigin.RIGHT,
                font: '20px Helvetica',
                fillColor: Cesium.Color.WHITE,
                outlineWidth: 1,
                style: Cesium.LabelStyle.FILL,
                pixelOffset: new Cesium.Cartesian3(0,0,0)
            }
            });
            //Tried to update the pixelOffset value
            entity.pixelOffset = new Cesium.Cartesian3(200, 20);
```

But nothing happens. I logged the entity on console and the value of pixelOffset appears, but there is no change on the map.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your code.

1. The last line assigning `entity.pixelOffset` is incorrect.  It should be `entity.label.pixelOffset`.  That's the main reason your doesn't work.
2. `LabelGraphics.pixelOffset` is a `Cartesian2` instance, not a `Cartesian3` instance.  The code will work either with either because of JavaScript's dynamic typing, but it's good practice to use the correct type and will help the browser better optimize the code.

There's also no need to set the pixelOffset during creation time, since the default is `Cartesian2.ZERO` and creating a new instance will just waste memory.

Here's an updated working version of your code:

```
var entity = mapa.getViewer.entities.add({
    position: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-75.1641667, 39.9522222),
    billboard: {
        image: pinBuilder.fromColor(Cesium.Color.SALMON, 48),
        verticalOrigin: Cesium.VerticalOrigin.BOTTOM
    },
    label: {
        text: ' Ponto',
        verticalOrigin: Cesium.VerticalOrigin.TOP,
        horizontalOrigin: Cesium.HorizontalOrigin.RIGHT,
        font: '20px Helvetica',
        fillColor: Cesium.Color.WHITE,
        outlineWidth: 1,
        style: Cesium.LabelStyle.FILL
    }
});

entity.label.pixelOffset = new Cesium.Cartesian2(200, 20);
```